# Linux Hibernate after a Stand By period

Tags: power-management, linux-mint

I've been trying to find a way to emulate the windows xp behavoir regarding hibernation/stand-by. In windows xp the system first goes to stand-by and, after a designated period of time, it wakes-up and enters into hibernation (suspend-to-disk). This feature is great but it don't seems to work un linux
BTW I'm running GNOME Linux Mint Isadora.
Any hints?

Regards
Drnoone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linux calls this “suspend-to-both”. Under Ubuntu (which Mint is based on), you can invoke it from the command line with `sudo s2both` or `sudo pm-suspend-hybrid`. I don't know if there is a GUI for it in Mint. Beware that [support for suspend-to-both has been buggy in recent Ubuntu versions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1685/whither-hybrid-suspend) (which may justify its not being available from the GUI).