# Laptop Power saving when in standby

Tags: laptop, power-management

After my laptop goes into standby is there any way to put it into hibernate when the battery reaches a critical level?

Comment: It's built into my Sony Vaio software. Are you sure you don't have a similar utility on your PC?

Comment: Windows can make it hibernate after being alseep for a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want “hybrid suspend”, also called “hybrid sleep” or “suspend to both”. See a [Linux discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/193401/linux-hibernate-after-a-stand-by-period), [Windows discussion](https://superuser.com/questions/62331/what-is-hybrid-sleep-in-windows-7).

Comment: That's not suitable for laptops and it's usually disabled on laptops by default, as it would make the laptop write a complete hibernation memory dump every time it goes to sleep, therefore using much more battery power than standard sleep.

Comment: @jason404: Why would it be unsuitable for laptops? If you want to minimize battery consumption, you need to suspend to disk only unless it's only for a few minutes, as RAM power consumption is non-negligible. The point of suspend to both is to be able to resume quickly.

Comment: Have you actually tried using hybrid sleep/suspend-to-both on a laptop? It's not practical, as everytime you close the lid it will save the complete RAM state, which takes some time when you have a lot of RAM and also uses more power, as every time your laptop goes to sleep after not being used for a little while, it will go through the whole process. This ends up using a lot more battery power than you would have used when just using Sleep mode instead.

Comment: Also, the benefit of Hybrid sleep over normal Sleep on desktop PCs is that it is robust against power outages, which is not relevant on laptops, as they effectively have built-in UPSs.